# not able to read syslog using C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am able to write syslog data using client on UDP port 514.

Now from same port I want to read the syslog data, why below line of code saying "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

```
UdpClient udpListener = new UdpClient(514);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This port(UDP 514) is already occupied by your or some other application.
To see who using it you can with a command line tool for windows:

```
netstat -ano
```

And find process witch using this port by PID from netstat output

Try get data not directly from port. [For example by lib](https://labs.rebex.net/syslog)

Comment: Thanks, but even with above library, I m getting same error